# Ruby on Rails ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error for a given user role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner to Ruby on Rails and this is an ruby on rails that was developed by someone.

There are 2 types of users: registered user with "user" role and registered user with "admin" role.

This too many redirects only happens if the user's role = "user", but not so if the user is "admin".  I haven't figure out why yet.

First, if the user is the admin, I will get this in the log:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-07-22 18:18:17 -0700
Processing by ProductsController#home as HTML
  ^[[1m^[[35mUser Load (0.1ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
controller_path: products
resource: product
method: product_params
after the parms setting => ${params}
Debugging in the Ability.rb...
User: #<User:0x007fe6d7f0f670>
user is admin
  ^[[1m^[[36mProduct Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "products".* FROM "products"^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35mVersion Load (1.1ms)^[[0m  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions"
  ^[[1m^[[36mReltype Load (1.0ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "reltypes".* FROM "reltypes"^[[0m
```

and many more SQL statements; I would love to simplify that but that is a different question and another learning opportunity.

If the user is a regular user, the "redirect" will happen right after user is regular user

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-07-22 18:25:23 -0700
Processing by ProductsController#home as HTML
  ^[[1m^[[36mUser Load (0.1ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["id", 11]]
controller_path: products
resource: product
method: product_params
after the parms setting => ${params}
Debugging in the Ability.rb...
User: #<User:0x007fe6d13dca88>
user is regular user
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-07-22 18:25:23 -0700
Processing by ProductsController#home as HTML
  ^[[1m^[[35mUser Load (0.1ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
controller_path: products
resource: product
method: product_params
...repeat... for many more
```

My guess is that the landing page is trying to pull all the data for use in this page and each SQL triggers a redirect...  But first, I like to find why does it make a difference between an user with role user vs. role admin.  I will worry about optimization later.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :groupings
  resources :platforms
  resources :versions
  resources :reltypes
  resources :products

  # Devise stuff
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  resources :users, :controller => "users"
  unauthenticated :user do
    resources :products, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :versions, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :reltypes, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :platforms, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :groupings, only: [:index, :show]
  end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root to: 'products#home'

  namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
    resources :platforms
    resources :versions
    resources :reltypes
    resources :products
    resources :groupings
  end
end
```

Next, controllers/application.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # Devise: redirect to login page if user not logged in
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  before_filter do
    resource = controller_path.singularize.to_sym
    method = "#{resource}_params"
    Rails.logger.debug("controller_path: #{controller_path}")
    Rails.logger.debug("resource: #{resource}")
    Rails.logger.debug("method: #{method}")

    params[resource] &&= send(method) if respond_to?(method, true)
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, roles: [])}
  end

  # CanCan: if user authorization fails, catch and modify
  check_authorization :unless => :devise_controller?

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
end
```

Here is the models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_save :default_values

  def default_values
  #    self.role ||= 'user'
    self.role = "user"
  end

  def is?(requested_role)
    self.role == requested_role
  end
end
```

Finally, I found this models/activity.rb (I tried to put some debugging statements here:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    Rails.logger.debug("Debugging in the Ability.rb...")
    Rails.logger.debug("User: #{user}")

    if user.is? "admin"
      Rails.logger.debug("user is admin")
      can :manage, :all
    else
      Rails.logger.debug("user is regular user")
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Added the controllers/products_controller.rb (as suggested by Sri Vishnu Totakura).  I skipped the code for update/destroy just to save a little space.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource #for CanCan

  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def home
    @products = Product.all
    @versions = Version.all
    @platforms = Platform.all
    @reltypes = Reltype.all
    @prevrels = Prevrel.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    # puts "params for new: "
    # puts params
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    puts "params for create: "
    puts params
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
     ...
  end

  def destroy
     ...
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      @versions = @product.versions
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Comment: There might be some code that causes this in the `ProductsController#home` action. Would be helpful if you could paste the code from the `ProductsController`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is here:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
end
```

For some reason when you're not an admin, that exception is raised, and you fall into a loop, as you redirect to `ProductsController#home` which is the `root to: 'products#home'`

I don't see your products controller code, but the problem should be there. Let me know.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me. I was testing cancan abilities on the home page, but forgot that when access is denied I'd set it to `rescue_from` (same as OP) and redirect to the home page, creating a circular reference.  An amusing problem that was tricky to diagnose but easy to understand with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not comment or upvote [Paulo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470032/paulo-abreu) 's answer I am leaving this here for everyone having a similar problem.

His answer made me take a better look in my controller that was causing the infinite redirects and particularly the action that was triggered and eventually solve this.

I was using `devise/cancancan` as well.

Specifically, I had a `companies_controller.rb`.

Furthermore, in a before_action I had something like the following

```
before_action :set_company, only: :show
```

and the set_company action was this

```
def set_company
   ...
   authorize! params[:action].to_sym, @company || Company
end
```

As soon as I removed the authorize! call the redirect loop stopped.
I haven't figured what caused the loop, since my user roles seemed just fine, but this was definitely the cause.